# How to enable whole program optimization with g++ and CMake

Tags: cmake, g++, lto

What's the correct way to enable whole program optimization with CMake and g++? I know about CMake's `INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION` variable, but it looks like there are additional optimizations available if I specify `-fuse-linker-plugin`, `-ffat-lto-objects`, and possibly others.

What's the most aggressive optimization I can do in terms of cross-object optimization, and how do I enable this with g++ and CMake?

Comment: If you now the command line options for the linker, then in CMake project you may add them via `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable. Do not expect that CMake has a convenient variable or a target's property (like `INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION`) for every compiler/linker feature. Normaly, they add only features supported by all well-known compilers, or at least by several of them.

Comment: Use `target_compile_options` and `target_link_options`. Also, the good idea is to check if the compiler used to build your project supports them (e.g., using `check_cxx_compiler_flag`).